# filter method is called twice android edittext on change keyboard language

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-input-filter

I like to convert on the fly letters from cyrillic to latin. For example when user enter cyrillic letter I like to convert letter to latin. Here is the code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    test = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.test);
    InputFilter filter = new InputFilter() {
        TransliterationHelper tr = new TransliterationHelper();

        public CharSequence filter(CharSequence source, int start, int end,
                                   Spanned dest, int dstart, int dend) {

            if (tr.isAlphaCyrilic(source.toString())) {
                String convertedString = tr.returnLatinForCyrilic(source.toString());
                return convertedString.toUpperCase();
            } else if (tr.isAlpha(source.toString()))
                return source.toString().toUpperCase();
            else
                return "";


            return null;
        }
    };

    test.setFilters(new InputFilter[]{filter});
}
```

Here is isAlphaCyrilic function:

```
  public static boolean isAlphaCyrilic(String s) {
    boolean isCyrilic = false;
    for (char c : s.toCharArray()) {
        if (Character.UnicodeBlock.of(c) == Character.UnicodeBlock.CYRILLIC) {
            isCyrilic = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    return isCyrilic;
}
```

Here is the code for isAlpha

```
public static boolean isAlpha(String s) {
    String pattern = "^[a-zA-Z ]*$";
    if (s.matches(pattern)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The function returnLatinForCyrilic, return matched character for cyrillic letter:

```
public String returnLatinForCyrilic(String s) {
    String strTranslated = cyrilicToLatinMap.get(s);
    return strTranslated;
}
```

For example I enter only latin letters or cyrillic letters everything works ok, but when I enter cyrillic letter after latin (I changed keyboard language) method filter called again, and I don't like that.

Does someone has some idea?

Answer (score 2):

I put `android:inputType="textNoSuggestions"`
so the method filter was not called twice.